# istream overload not working

Tags: c++, overloading, istream

AS REQUESTED, ACTUAL FILES:

d_date.h
http://pastebin.com/AFe4XE2c

d_except.h
http://pastebin.com/8QE2m8ia

d_date.cpp
http://pastebin.com/dgpxLWKv

input.dat
http://pastebin.com/XUpRcu9E

I did a bare bones program similar to the following one, and I got similar errors.

CLASS:

```
#ifndef DATE_CLASS
#define DATE_CLASS

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

//#include "d_except.h"

using namespace std;

class date
{
   public:
      date ();

      //ADDED
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const date&); 
      friend istream& operator>>(istream&, date&);

   private:
      int month, day, year;
            // private members that specify the date

};


#endif
```

AND DATE.CPP:

```
#ifndef DATE_CPP
#define DATE_CPP

#include "date.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const date& date1){
     char blah;
     ostr << blah;
 }

 istream& operator>>(istream& istr, date& date1){
     istr >> "5";
     return istr;
 }


#endif
```

DRIVER.CPP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
//#include "d_except.h"

using namespace std;

void main (void)
{
    date date1;
    date date2;
}
```

AND THE ERRORS (not posting the length list but the ones towards the end:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(float &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(429): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(447): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, const char [2])'
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

THE LENGTHIER VERSION:
(IGNORE THE FOLLOWING)
I get hideous warnings when I use the following:

```
class date
{
   public:
    //irrelevant (hopefully) functions not shown are here
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const date&); 
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, date&);

   private:
    int month, day, year;
}

 ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const date& date1){
    ostr << date1.getDay() << "/" << date1.getMonth() << "/" << date1.getYear() << " "; 
    return ostr;
 }

 istream& operator>>(istream& istr, date& date1){
     int d, m, y;
     char ch;
     istr >> d >> ch >> m >> ch >> y >> ch;
     date1.setDay(d);
     date1.setMonth(m);
     date1.setYear(y);
     return istr;
 }
```

My input is input.dat and specified in the DeBugging page in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.  I get repetitions of the following with different variables after the >>.  As  best I can tell, there is some problem with istream using date. I think it kind of "tells" me in the last line of this post what the problem is, but I still don't get it.

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(429): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(447): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, date)'
```

The actual .cpp that runs this stuff is:

```
void main (void)
{
    date date1;
    date date2;

    cout << "Enter date1 and date2:" << endl;

    while (cin >> date1 >> date2)
    {
        cout << "Printing date1 and date2" << endl;
        cout << date1 << endl << date2 << endl;
                //and more...

}
```

ADDENDUM:

```
class date
{
   public:
      date (int mm=1, int dd=1, int yyyy=1900);
            // supply date in format MM/DD/YYYY
            // preconditions: 1 <= mm <= 12,
            //                1 <= dd <= daysInMonth()

      void writeShortDate () const;
            // output the date in the format "MM/DD/YYYY"
      void writeLongDate () const;
            // output the date in the format "month day, year"

      void incrementDate(int ndays);
            // add ndays days to the date
            // precondition: 0 <= ndays <= 365

      int numberOfDays() const;
            // return the number of days into the year

      int getMonth() const;// done
            // return the month as integer value 1 to 12
      int getDay() const; //done
            // return day of the month
      int getYear() const;  //done
            // return the year

      void setMonth(int mm); //done
            // update the month
            // precondition: 1 <= mm <= 12
      void setDay(int dd); //done
            // update the day
            // precondition: 1 <= dd <= daysInMonth()
      void setYear(int yyyy); //done
            // update the year
            // precondition:  if the date is February 29,
            //                yyyy must be a leap year
      int daysInMonth() const;
            // return number of days in the month

      bool isLeapYear() const;
            // is the current year a leap year (true/false)

      //ADDED
      bool operator< (const date&) const;
      bool operator> (const date&) const;
      date operator++ ();
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const date&); 
      friend istream& operator>>(istream&, date&);
   private:
      enum monthName {Jan = 1, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun,
                      Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec};
            // private type used by date

      int month, day, year;
            // private members that specify the date

};
```

AND:

```
#ifndef DRIVER_H
#define DRIVER_H

#include <iostream>
#include "d_date.h"
#include "d_except.h"

using namespace std;

void main (void)
{
    date date1;
    date date2;

    cout << "Enter date1 and date2:" << endl;

    while (cin >> date1 >> date2)
    {
        cout << "Printing date1 and date2" << endl;
        cout << date1 << endl << date2 << endl;

        if (date1 == date2) 
            cout << date1 << " is equal to " << date2 << endl;

        if (date1 != date2) 
            cout << date1 << " is not equal to " << date2 << endl;

        if (date1 < date2) 
            cout << date1 << " is less than " << date2 << endl;

        if (date1 > date2) 
            cout << date1 << " is greater than " << date2 << endl;

        ++date1;
        ++date2;

        cout << "Increment of date1: " << date1 << endl;
        cout << "Increment of date2: " << date2 << endl;

        cout << endl << "---End of Run---" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter date1 and date2:" << endl;
    }


}
```

This is for school, and I hate to post nearly the entire assignment, but I can't fix the errors.  Above is the more detailed version of date.h and driver.cpp.

I don't know what I did, but now the only error I get is:

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Also, forgot to mention...overloading code for driver.cpp is not shown here but causes no errors.

Comment: Semicolon after class-definition?

Comment: It looks like some (the beginning) of the error is missing. Also, [don't use `void main`](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main).

Comment: I can't see function `getDay()` etc. been declared nor defined. Could you show us your real code?

Comment: Unrelated but `void main(void)` isn't a proper main function signature in C++. Use `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

Comment: With minimal changes (semicolon after class, changing getters and setters to data members, adding a finishing brace in `main`), [it works](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2bx7vU$6). A complete, minimal sample would help more.

Comment: @chris: I did the same and it indeed compiles also on VC10. I believe the definition of `date` the OP posted is not complete, and the part which is missing (maybe some conversions that make `operator <<` ambiguous?) is the root cause of the problem

Comment: @AndyProwl, I'm not sure. Anyway, why are the operators friends if they use presumably public setters and getters? Like that, they don't need any form of declaration in the class.

Comment: @user963070: `operator ==` is not defined, and I get compilation errors for that. Are we still missing a part?

Comment: By the way, `operator++()` should return a reference.

Comment: @user963070 : A lot of overloading was done as the rest of the assignment.  I don't want to post the entire code because if it is for homework, but if it is necessary I can.

Comment: @user963070: Well, the code you posted compiles for me on VC10, so the problem must be in the overloading

Comment: @user963070, Can you copy your project over to a new one and make something like the first code block you posted that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @user963070  Yes, it will be a couple of minutes...

Comment: @usesr963070 I scaled it down, and I get similar errors.

Comment: @user963070, Thank you for scaling it down, but I'm afraid I can't reproduce it. I did, however, have to make a few changes: Adding a return statement to `operator<<`, making the bodies of `operator<<` and `operator>>` just a single return statement, and changing the return type of `main`, as GCC actually gives an error for that. Other than that, include guards should only be used with headers. Implementation files don't have the same problem as headers have that warrants that solution. The reason I made these changes is because the real code you posted before doesn't exhibit those problems.

Comment: @user963070: `istr >> "5";` makes no sense, is this your real code?

Comment: Oh wait, the `istr >> "5";` would give you the error you posted under the shorter sample. I still don't see anything like that in the other code, though.

Comment: I had to switch the istr >> 5 and ostr << blah and then it works for the short code.

Comment: Reading into `"5"` is a strange idea...

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that there is a problem with `operator >>` while `trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, date)'`. In fact, in your overload of `operator >>` for your `date` class you have this instruction in the last version of the code you posted:

```
istr >> "5";
```

Normally, the second parameter in the signature of an `operator >>` overload is a non-const reference to an object which is supposed to be extracted (deserialized) from a stream. However, the string literal `"5"` has type `char [2]`, and no overload exist of `operator >>` for that type. That makes sense: how could you extract an object from a stream and store it into a string literal?

Hence, the error you get. I suspect your previous versions of the code were affected by similar problems.

Comment: I was wondering myself whether there was some `date` temporary used like that.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or sound inconsiderate because you were right about the problems you mentioned, but my structure code suffered from that mistake, while the stuff I actually, ironically used did not (embarrassingly) , and the program still gives all the errors it had before.  There is a little red squiggly under all the overloading symbols on the large program.  I do not know how to get rid of them.  driver.h cannot reach d_date.h???

Comment: @user963070: once again, without seeing your *real* code, we cannot do anything to help you. Please post it somewhere.

Comment: After fixing a bunch of obvious problems (`void main`, `date` has a constructor that isn't defined anywhere, `operator <<` doesn't return anything, and switching what `<<` and `>>` do) it compiles just fine with clang++-3.1.

Comment: @AndyProwl:  d_date.h
http://pastebin.com/AFe4XE2c

d_except.h
http://pastebin.com/8QE2m8ia

d_date.cpp
http://pastebin.com/BfkSjsCL

input.dat
http://pastebin.com/XUpRcu9E

Comment: d_except.h was coded by the teacher, so I don't think it's buggy.

Comment: @AndyProwl - added real code.

Comment: @vonbrand - why would you switch what `<<` and `>>` do?

Comment: @SteveFolly, because as written it reads into `"5"` and writes from an uninitialized `char`...

Comment: My one clue is that all the operators involving dates are underlined in a red squiggly line in the driver.cpp, indicating something is wrong with all of them???

Comment: @user963070: Operators `==` and `!=` for `date` are completely missing: no declaration and no definition. The other operators (`>>`, `<<`, `>`, `<`, `++`) are declared but not defined: where are the definitions? None of the files you posted contains them.

Comment: @AndyProwl: http://pastebin.com/dgpxLWKv  is d_date.cpp   I am so sorry.  I am usually not this scatterbrained.

Comment: @user963070: it compiles fine under GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2, I just pasted everything together and was able to run it.

Comment: @AndyProwl I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.  Also, could the problem be that I an not accessing input.dat right?  I put it under Command Arguments in the Debugging pane.  I have Linux.  I'm just not very good at it.    What would I type in Linux to use it?

Comment: @user963070: What is the problem you are having? Does it compile and run? I thought it did not

Comment: @AndyProwl:  It doesn't compile.  It gives me all the ugly long long errors mentioned above.  I was hoping from your post to get it to run under Linux if you said it worked.

Comment: @user963070: so I tried not merging everything in one file. There are several problems. First, your `operator ==` and `operator !=` are not visible in `driver.cpp`. Add a declaration for those operator in `date.h`, then it will compile. However, you will get linker errors for multiply defined functions. That's because you define free functions in headers without using the `inline` keyword. Either add it, or only *declare* functions in header files and *define* them in source files.

Comment: I realized I forgot the "<" in the file input box (DAMN) in Visual Studio, which is good...it's just now I get different errors, one for each overloading operator in driver.cpp like such:   Error 21 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'date' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\erice\documents\c++_2\lab02\driver.cpp 38 1 c2_lab02  Will fix what you said.

Comment: @user963070: Sorry, I think I can't help you further. These errors have changed already 5-6 times since you posted the question. Just take care of following the advices you have been given so far. If nothing helps, just start from scratch, many times it helps.

Comment: @AndyProwl:  No problem.  Thanks for the help!  I will probably give you credit when I figure out what my major error is.

Comment: @AndyProwl:  the solution for most of the errors went away when I put them in a single file and used g++, as per your recommendation.  Can you suggest that as a solution so I can credit your suggestion?

Comment: @user963070: putting everything in a single file was not my suggestion. It was just a quick attempt from my side to figure out what was wrong. Putting everything in one single place is a bad design practice in general, so I cannot suggest it :-)